# Send PHP curl to Mozilla push API

Tags: php, firefox, curl, service-worker

I want to send PHP curl to Firefox push API so I tried something like this:

```
   $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v1"
                    . "/gAAAAABX8Nj8fzlle0QZhO8Ve_b-UBdONugvPvzDRifHIMCX4kxg3nefboz4vRGZuWIhde8jd_2_1U4mUenr55blIiR2XFytEd0r6iYuLHgTIZJ2U6Kb84iNCMwkh95mKD-gi8zMoKEh" );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( "TTL: 86400" ) );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $data;
```

Did I do something wrong ?

This is what I got from my sub.endpoint in the client :
`https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v1/gAAAAABX8Nj8fzlle0QZhO8Ve_b-UBdONugvPvzDRifHIMCX4kxg3nefboz4vRGZuWIhde8jd_2_1U4mUenr55blIiR2XFytEd0r6iYuLHgTIZJ2U6Kb84iNCMwkh95mKD-gi8zMoKEh`

Answer (score 0):

The correct HTTP method that you should use is 'POST', not 'PUT'.

For reference, read [section 5 of the Web Push standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-webpush-protocol-10#section-5).